# How do I initialize TinyMCE on a ajax loaded textarea in 4.x?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am upgrading to tinyMCE 4.x and I am attempting to initialize tinyMCE on a textarea loaded via AJAX.  In 3.x I did something of the sort: [TinyMCE - attach to divs loaded via AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987757/tinymce-attach-to-divs-loaded-via-ajax-calls) but this does not seem to work in 4.x.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
tinymce.remove();
tinymce.init();
```

This works well!

Comment: use tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });  in ajax

Comment: This worked well for me, but it took me a little bit to realize that I would have to replace the other information inside the parenthesis for the `.init()` function. Just throwing that out there for anyone else who may be confused why it might not work with just `.init()`. You need to include the `{selector:'textarea'}` bit inside the parenthesis and complete the function call like so:

`tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'})`

Answer (score 12):

In TinyMCE **4.x** *mceRemoveControl* and *mceAddControl* have been removed. You have to use *mceRemoveEditor* and *mceAddEditor* instead.

Got it from: [[Resolved] mceRemoveControl and mceAddControl in tinymce 4](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31256)

Otherwise, you can reload tinymce.init({ ... }) but that should not be the way as it would be slower.

Comment: the link is dead :(

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987757/tinymce-attach-to-divs-loaded-via-ajax-calls or https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Command_identifiers/
 Didn't get is working with remove() and init() . This way it works really.

Answer (score 7):

You can load TinyMCE after including textarea with the following code:

```
//initialize tinyMCE in page
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
```

Comment: I was calling init with some custom options to load the static textareas, so I ended up extracting my initialize into a function and calling that when the ajax call is complete.

Answer (score 1):

just for then running into the same problem.

I solved the problem with wrapping the init Script into a function like this.

> in my init.js file

```html
initializeTinyMce();
function initializeTinyMce(selector){
  if(selector == undefined){selector = 'textarea';}
  ...
  tinymce.init({
    selector: selector,
    ...
  });
}
```

so on your ajax request result you add

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    initMCE('textarea#someId');
  });
</script>
```

works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });

just use this in ajax and if you are not able to pick the value then Before submitting the form, call

tinyMCE.triggerSave();