# Jquery/Tinymce - Loading tinymce after ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

So i have a page that submits a form using ajax and then on success reloads the data/form.  When the page initially loads, tinymce loads just fine with the page.  When i submit the form, the form reappears but its just a textarea and not the tinymce.  I think I have to initialize the tinymce again on success but i have tried and can't seem to get it to work. My Code:

My code:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/form.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {                    
               $("#formcontainer").html(data);
                tinymce.init({
                selector: ".Htmltextarea"
               });       
            },
            error: function(){
                  alert('error handing here');
            }
        }); 
});
```

I also have the tinymce.init on the parent page where the form loads via ajax.  Again, when I initially load the form, all works fines, the Tinymce loads.  It just when i submit the form via ajax and the success/data is returned that I get the submitted form but the tinymce is gone.  How to I get tinymce after ajax form submit? Thannks.

Attempt also not working:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/form.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {                    
               $("#formcontainer").html(data);
               tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, ".Htmltextarea"); 
               tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, ".Htmltextarea");  
            },
            error: function(){
                  alert('error handing here');
            }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568238/how-do-i-initialize-tinymce-on-a-ajax-loaded-textarea-in-4-x

Comment: @kepi please see update to my post.  Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        // tinyMCE.triggerSave(); // uncomment this line if tinyMCE is giving blank response
        type: "POST",
        url: "/form.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(data) {                    
           $("#formcontainer").html(data);
            tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, ".Htmltextarea");
        },
        error: function(){
              alert('error handing here');
        }
    }); 
});
```