# Reinitilize the tinymce on ajax page load ?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Reinitilize the tinymce on ajax page load ?   i am using version 4 and used classes instead of id.

Using this on page refresh and after ajax page load:

```
tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : MY_TEXTAREA_CLASS,
        plugins : 'link',
        menubar : false,
        height : 250,
        resize: false,
    });
```

Comment: already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568238/how-do-i-initialize-tinymce-on-a-ajax-loaded-textarea-in-4-x

Comment: got it , Thanks , actually issue was in editor id :)